# How to retry until a IP address is assigned with Ansible and vmware_vm_info?

Tags: ansible, vmware

I want to retry until I GET an ip_address: with the vm_info: module for a host (guest_name:). The problem is that sometimes the provisioned vm has not booted and therefore I can't get an IP address

Question:

How should I define my role, to repeat until ip_address is defined?

```
---
 - name: Get virtual machine info
   vmware_vm_info:
     hostname: '{{ vsphere_host }}'
     username: '{{ vsphere_user }}'
     password: '{{ vsphere_password }}'
     validate_certs: false    
     folder: '/{{ vsphere_datacenter }}/vm'
   delegate_to: localhost
   register: vm_info

 - debug:
     var:  vm_info


 - name: "Update host_var with new IP Address"
   set_fact: 
     ansible_host: "{{ item.ip_address }}"
     ansible_hostname: "{{ item.guest_name }}"
     regexp: "^ansible_host:" 
   with_items:
     - "{{ vm_info.virtual_machines | json_query(query) }}"
   vars:
     query: "[?guest_name=='{{ hostname }}']"
   delegate_to: localhost
```

This is the debug of register vm_info:

```
ok: [1-Europe-Cisco-Site1-2-pci] => 
 vm_info:
   changed: false
   failed: false
   virtual_machines:
   - attributes: {}
     cluster: null
     esxi_hostname: 51.89.43.64
     guest_fullname: Other 3.x Linux (64-bit)
     guest_name: 1-Europe-Cisco-Site2-2-guest
     ip_address: ''
     mac_address:
     - 00:50:56:91:41:b7
     - 00:50:56:91:80:67
     - 00:50:56:91:f2:a3
     power_state: poweredOn
     tags: []
     uuid: 42110cfc-0b31-5de2-659d-6f8fe47e8136
     vm_network: {}
   - attributes: {}
     cluster: null
     esxi_hostname: 51.89.43.64
     guest_fullname: Other 3.x Linux (64-bit)
     guest_name: 1-Europe-Cisco-Site1-2-guest
     ip_address: ''
     mac_address:
     - 00:50:56:91:07:e1
     - 00:50:56:91:b0:79
     - 00:50:56:91:d4:5a
     power_state: poweredOn
     tags: []
     uuid: 4211db9d-5608-14fd-1c9b-6cfc470c29c7
     vm_network: {}
   - attributes: {}
     cluster: null
     esxi_hostname: 51.89.43.64
     guest_fullname: Other 3.x Linux (64-bit)
     guest_name: 1-Europe-Cisco-Site2-1-guest
     ip_address: ''
     mac_address:
     - 00:50:56:91:89:ac
     - 00:50:56:91:12:c7
     - 00:50:56:91:e3:0b
     - 00:50:56:91:de:b3
     power_state: poweredOn
     tags: []
     uuid: 421126d9-e74a-2db2-b58c-0a09571d9b29
     vm_network: {}
```

Until only works for one task, but I need to define here 2x tasks:
1.get vm_info
2.loop thru vm_info and define the host_ip

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using the vmware_guest_info module the following like?
In the following playbook, the vmware_guest_info will execute until getting an IP address from a virtual machine using the schema and properties options.

```yaml
---
- name: Example Playbook
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - name: Operate a virtual machine to powered on
      vmware_guest:
        hostname: "{{ vcenter_hostname }}"
        username: "{{ vcenter_username }}"
        password: "{{ vcenter_password }}"
        validate_certs: false
        datacenter: "{{ datacenter_name }}"
        name: "{{ vm_name }}"
        state: poweredon

    - name: Gather a virtual machine info
      vmware_guest_info:
        hostname: "{{ vcenter_hostname }}"
        username: "{{ vcenter_username }}"
        password: "{{ vcenter_password }}"
        validate_certs: false
        datacenter: "{{ datacenter_name }}"
        name: "{{ vm_name }}"
        schema: vsphere
        properties:
          - guest.ipAddress
      retries: 60
      delay: 10
      until: gather_vm_info.instance.guest.ipAddress is not none
      register: gather_vm_info

    - debug: var=gather_vm_info
```

Comment: Thank you very much, you solved one of my biggest problems :) Sometimes you have to search for other modules, instead try to solve something, which can't be done in the module !!!

Comment: One additional question, how do you print, when the until loop is retrying the task? I just saw it, it delays the print until it get's a success!?

Comment: Sorry, can you please tell me the meaning of the print?  
Do you want to print the task result output while executing the until processing?

Comment: thanks sky_jokerxx, I solved it. However, I have an other problem now. When I get the IP address from the vyOS VM, I always got the DHCP address, however, when I run the PlayBook again, I get the static IP address from eht1 or eht2, but not from eth0.

Is there a way in VMWare to specify which IP address will be used as guest.ipAddress?